# Java Cannot Find Symbol Error In Do loop

Tags: java

on the last line of this code Im getting the error that it can't find the symbol wallet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int money = money();
boolean again = again("Ready");
do {
    int bet = bet(money);
    int wallet = wallet(bet);
    Deck deck = dealDeck();
    int com = comDeal(deck);
    int user = userDeal(deck);
    int userTotal = userHit(user, deck);
    int comTotal = comHit(com, deck, userTotal);
    int winner = whoWon(userTotal, comTotal);
    again = again("Play again");
}
while (again && wallet > 0);
```

Comment: try declaring `wallet` outside of your `do while` block

Comment: Is wallet a variable or a method or both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int wallet` is defined inside the `do-while` loop. Using it outside of it like in the condition of the `while` is not allowed since it's out of scope.

Just declare this variable before the `do-while` loop:

```
int money = money();
int wallet = 0;
boolean again = again("Ready");
do {
    //rest of code here...
} while (<condition>);
```